# Scope bar on mac

Tags: macos, cocoa, scope

Doses anyone know how to create a scope bar on mac application?
The apple UI document always mention scope bar,But I can't find any System controller like "NSScopebar".
I don't wanna use "MGScopeBar".
Does anyone has other idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a shame, but there is no such control. If you don't want third-party code, subclass `NSView` and use `NSGradient` in `drawRect:` to create the same look.